# How to make a working login functions for my website?

Tags: javascript, python, php, css

I am just entered this game since last December. Now I finished HTML CSS and a little bit of Java Script yet I got stuck at this stage: I can do basic styling but I don't know how to make it interactive.

So my question is :

how can I make a login function for websites, which can gives visitor an account  (sign up, login, forgot password) that can do basic things like comment , add to basket and favorite a product?

Don't need to be specific, please just highlight which language is involved in which stage.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: have you setup a server to handle api calls? do you have a database to store user information? there are plenty of tutorials on youtube on how to build a website. I think you should start there

Comment: This is not an easy task, you need a back end language like PHP or ASP that will talk with a database to record new users and vet returning users that enter proper credentials. Creating a ***secure*** log in is something to take **VERY seriously** and should NEVER be attempted if you are not sure of what you are doing, especially if your users will be entering vital personal data. There is plenty of information out there on how to log into a database, but doing it securely should be your top priority! One option: [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

Comment: _"Don't need to be specific, please just highlight which language is involved in which stage."_ - Any server side language would work. You really need to do some proper research before asking. There are _many many_ tutorials about building login-systems out there (plus many frameworks that can help you since it's easy to mess it up and make it insecure.) Questions here _need_ to be specific and you should have decided on a language (asking for recommendations/suggestions are off-topic, plus we have no idea what you already know or to what level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I finished HTML CSS and a little bit of Java Script

So your site is what is called a [`static website`](https://techterms.com/definition/staticwebsite).

---

If you want to allow login and data storing, you need a [`dynamic website`](https://www.spiralytics.com/blog/what-are-dynamic-websites/), that requires one of this technologies:

- `PHP`
- [`ASP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) (check also `ASP.NET`)
- `Node.js` (with `express` or `http` module)
- `Django` (`Python`'s library)
- A few others...

All this technologies are called [`server-side`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction) languages/technologies, and the most used for long years has been `PHP`, that now has some strong rivals in terms of usage.

Answer (score -1):

You can use only html/js to create a website. But, if you need authentication, post comments, a server side is needed.
A js can call easely an API to authenticate (server side) and post comments with XHR. You have to create it. You need to know how Authentication headers works for server side. You need to have a database (sql, file or nosql, it's your choice) to save the users datas and rights.